# Selenium functions not working after Chrome Driver is Set Up

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dll, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set up a selenium driver with a signed in chrome profile because I was hoping to bypass 2FA on certain websites but when I run the program I get no errors and the first selenium command will not execute. **Anything after `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` doesn't run.**
To set it up i did the following;

1. Open cmd
2. cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
3. chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="[Created a folder in the project]"

The I wrote this

```
string path_profile = @"C:\Projects\TestingEnviornment\TestingEnviornment\driver\ChromeProfile";

Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
if (chromeInstances.Length > 0)
{
    // Chrome is running. Lets shut it down.
    Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM chrome.exe");
}
Thread.Sleep(2000);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument($@"--user-data- dir=C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"); //path_profile
options.AddArgument("--hide-crash-restore-bubble");
options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-logging");

Console.WriteLine("Driver Start Up");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
Console.WriteLine("Driver Start Standby");
try
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
    Console.WriteLine("End");
    driver.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("! ERROR !");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    driver.Close();
}
```

Here is a Sample of the output I get from my console
[image]

**Edit**: It seems to be a problem with this argument. It doesn't matter if I use my copied profile or the default one.

```
options.AddArgument($@"--user-data- dir=C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
```

Also adding the argument

```
options.AddArgument("profile-directory=Profile 1");
```

makes the selenium code start working again, but is a blank profile.

Answer (score 0):

In C# first, I usually add the Nuget Reference Selenium.WebDriver (requires Newtonsoft)
Once installed, add the using statement

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

    private void test(object sender, EventArgs e){

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  //The drivers comes installed
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://app.powerbi.com");
    try
       {
        //Example locate the name of the field of the web page
        var user = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
        var pass = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
        var botLogin = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("v-btn__content")); //ClassName of the button
        user.SendKeys("youruser");
        pass.SendKeys("passwordHere");
        botLogin.Click();

        //Wait to load the next view
        TimeSpan espera = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, espera);
        wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='/session']")));  //The Driver wait 10 seconds and verify this xpath or id 
        //or name appears
        // ... rest of code....
```

To know the name / id / xpath of the elements, I usually firts time browse the web site and Right Click over the element that I want Selenium interact with, and select "Inspect Element". This displays the HTML code for the element you clicked, and can figure out how to identify the Text field, or button or label.

Hope I help

Comment: I have to specify the chrome version because of other code this was just a sub section I took for testing. Also you didn't replicate my steps of what I did for creating a chrome profile so this is just a new browser which when navigating to the page after password will prompt a 2FA which you can't get around.
The hope was to get into a browser with the profile signed in which will automatically log you back in to the website as that user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the correct User Data folder which is located in AppData, you might want to try this one:

```
    options.AddArgument($@"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
```

Please make sure you kill the chrome.exe instance beforehand, because it will use the same session/profile which you personally use:

```
    Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM chrome.exe");
```

**Edit:** Have you thought about using automatic ChromeDriver downloads with [WebDriverManager NuGet](https://github.com/rosolko/WebDriverManager.Net)? If you install this dependency in your project you don't have the hassle of manually downloading the `chromedriver.exe`:

Using by (just change everything to Chrome if you want):

```
    Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM msedge.exe");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
    edgeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
    edgeOptions.AddArgument($@"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data");

// This line is responsible for the automatic download
    new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());

    var edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(edgeDriverService, edgeOptions);
```

**Edit2** If you Exception occurs, you might want to give the WebDriver more time to let the browser load Google, i.e. simple with a Thread.Sleep:

```
try
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
    Console.WriteLine("End");
    Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
    driver.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("! ERROR !");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    driver.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is actually worse. By using C:\Users\[MY NAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data , it tries to use any open chrome and throws a error for an existing chrome session already being open.

Comment: You have to kill chrome.exe before launching indeed. You cannot use your Chrome session while starting this. CMD “taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe” - if you do this before you can skip MFA and handle sessions by your profile.

Comment: I put that in and my program still will not run anything after the `driver = new ChromeDriver([Version], options)` line of code. It will open up a new browser with the correct profile but no navigate or commands work.

Comment: @CJP can you update your question with the new code?

Comment: I replaced the code with what is currently being used.

Comment: @CJP can you add a "Thread.Sleep(10000)" between "driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");" and "driver.Close();"? I think you have to give the browser more time to reach Google.

Comment: I can but it never navigates to google.com so that code never hits.

Comment: @CJP What is the exception?

Comment: I added that in hopes to catch any error but nothing is thrown. The only output I see is the second picture I linked in the post. If any exception is thrown its a 60s timeout -> 'The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51778/session timed out after 60 seconds.'

Comment: @CJP Try 'driver.Url = "https://google.com";' instead of GoToUrl